# Error when trying to generate schema using XJC

Tags: jaxb, xsd

So I parsed a bunch of XMLs to generate a giant schema file using trang which went fine. However, when I try to generate sources using xjc, I get the following error,

```
xjc reutersXMLSchema.xsd 
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] no-xsi: The {target namespace} of an attribute declaration must not match       'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'.
line 11 of file:/Users/cqin/Downloads/trang-20081028/xsi.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

The schema looks like the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"   targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:filter="http://schemas.reuters.com/ns/2006/04/14/rmds/webservices/news/filter"   xmlns:ns0="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/News_1"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.reuters.com/ns/2006/04/14/rmds/webservices/news/headlineml"  xmlns:cache_1="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2008/03/01/webservices/rkd/Cache_1"  xmlns:ns2="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/TokenManagement_1" xmlns:global="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/Common_1"  xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<xs:import   namespace="http://schemas.reuters.com/ns/2006/04/14/rmds/webservices/news/filter"   schemaLocation="filter.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.reuters.com/ns/2006/04/14/rmds/webservices/news/headlineml" schemaLocation="ns1.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/Common_1" schemaLocation="global.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/News_1" schemaLocation="reutersXMLSchema.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/TokenManagement_1" schemaLocation="ns2.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2008/03/01/webservices/rkd/Cache_1" schemaLocation="cache_1.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" schemaLocation="s.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" schemaLocation="a.xsd"/>
<xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:NCName"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Any idea why it won't work?

I've tried changing the targetNameSpace to something unique but I get more errors so I'm wondering if there is something I can do with the original error.

Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing same issue. After all this time can you recall how you fixed this? For me trang is creating an xsi.xsd that has  `<xs:attribute name="schemaLocation"/>` And xjc is complaining about that. I ran trang with a wildcard *.xml file for about 20 xml files in a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this isn't right:

```
targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

This is saying that the target namespace of your schema is actually the namespace of the Schema definition schema itself (i.e. the schema which defines the things like `<xs:schema>` and `<xs:import>` actually mean).  This schema is fixed, you can't write your own schema targeting it, which is why XJC is rejecting it.

> I've tried changing the targetNameSpace to something unique but I get more errors

Keep trying that, you'll get further than with what you have now. However, the fact that trang is generating this bad schema at all is suggestive that you've done something wrong further back along the line. Perhaps you asked it to generate a combined schema which included the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` schema itself, which is almost certainly not what you want to do.

Comment: Maybe the way I'm approaching my task is wrong and maybe you can provide some more insight. Basically I have a few XMLs that consist of several SOAP XML request/responses, about 6 of them. I just tried to use trang to combine all the XMLs into one giant schema as was advised to me by a co-worker. Is this the correct way to go about it in the first place?

Comment: @soulesschild: No, that doesn't sound like a good idea, from what you've told me. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically we're using a third party's API to build our own API for internal use. The way to call their API is using POST to post soap XML with the request and then receive a response in soap XML form as well. There are about 5 different requests and responses. The whole API is to be written in java.